# Finding components used 80% of the time from inventory movements

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, filtering

I'm trying to limit the 3D modelling I need to do to just the most common parts used in various categories. I want the cutoff to be at the point where, in order of use descending, I've covered 80% of total usage. I've gotten most of the way there but for some reason Microsoft SQL Management Studio complains when I try to do something to get that 80%.

Below is what I have, and there are no further columns really useful to the query other than perhaps more helper columns created within the query:

```
select
  PartFrequency.StockCode,
  InvMaster.Description,
  PartFrequency.Qty
from (
    select top 1000
      InvMaster.StockCode,
      sum(InvMovements.TrnQty) as Qty
    from InvMaster
    right join InvMovements
      on InvMaster.StockCode = InvMovements.StockCode
    where InvMaster.Description LIKE '%Bag/%'
    group by
      InvMaster.StockCode
    order by
      Qty DESC
) PartFrequency
left join InvMaster
  on PartFrequency.StockCode = InvMaster.StockCode
--where (sum(PartFrequency.Qty) over (order by PartFrequency.Qty DESC))<sum(PartFrequency.Qty)*0.8
order by
  Qty DESC
```

It's at the moment complaining about that WHERE clause, I've commented it out but included it so you could at least see conceptually what I'm going for.

Comment: What do you mean by "complains"? Whats the exact error? And I recommend making an effort to layout your query in a readable fashion. And using table aliases will make things clearer.

Comment: And you where clause doesn't make sense? What are you summing over? Sum with order by without a partition doesn't make any sense. We need sample data and desired results. Once you can work out what you are actually trying to sum, you may just need to put them in a sub-query since you can't use windows functions in a where clause.

Comment: You can't use window functions directly in WHERE. What you do is wrap it in subquery, something like: select * from (select *, sum(x) over(partition by y) as sumX) x where sumX = 5

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the window function inside the derived subquery.

- Note that this is a case of `SUM(SUM()) OVER` ie windowing over aggregation.
- You should add `rows unbounded preceding` to the running sum, otherwise you may get incorrect results (it's also faster).
- The right-join doesn't make much sense, because of the inner `where` which is filtering out, so you may as well do an inner-join.
- The other left-join is unnecessary as you have all the data you need. You can just add more grouping columns.

```sql
select
  PartFrequency.StockCode,
  PartFrequency.Description,
  PartFrequency.Qty
from (
    select top 1000
      ma.StockCode,
      ma.Description
      sum(mv.TrnQty) as Qty,
      sum(sum(mv.TrnQty)) over
          (order by sum(mv.TrnQty) DESC rows unbounded preceding) as Running
    from InvMaster ma
    join InvMovements mv
      on ma.StockCode = mv.StockCode
    where mv.Description LIKE '%Bag/%'
    group by
      ma.StockCode,
      ma.Description
    order by
      Qty DESC
) PartFrequency
where PartFrequency.Running < PartFrequency.Qty * 0.8
order by
  Qty DESC;
```

The logic of the final `where` doens't make sense to me, unless there are many negative values, but I can't see your data.